# how to close AlertDialog in Android Activity in before the finish() Activity

Tags: android

Here is My Log File

```
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316): Activity com.example.motiondetection.Stage1 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{535bdd60 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-698,281} that was originally added here
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.motiondetection.Stage1 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{535bdd60 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-698,281} that was originally added here
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at com.example.motiondetection.Stage1.playAgainMessage(Stage1.java:216)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at com.example.motiondetection.Stage1.checkBoundries(Stage1.java:133)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at com.example.motiondetection.Stage1.ballAnimation(Stage1.java:96)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at com.example.motiondetection.Stage1.onSensorChanged(Stage1.java:82)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:204)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-26 20:38:28.005: E/WindowManager(9316):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Code:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder displayMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(Stage1.this); 
    displayMessage.setMessage("Your Remaning Trial Is : " + trialGame);

    displayMessage.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
           @Override 
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank U...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    trialGame=3; 

    dialog.dismiss(); 

    finish(); 

         } 
     });
```

Comment: where is your  code?

Comment: Post the code where you create the `AlertDialog`

Comment: final AlertDialog.Builder displayMessage = new AlertDialog.Builder(Stage1.this);
  displayMessage.setMessage("Your Remaning Trial Is : " + trialGame);
  displayMessage.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank U...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    trialGame=3;
    dialog.dismiss();
    finish();
    
    
   }
  });

Comment: I just try to create a AlertDialog() and on Negative Button Close The Curent Activity

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dialog to a dismissListener, and just need to close the dialog in Your click method with dismiss();

```
    AlertDialog displayMessageDialog = displayMessage.create();

    displayMessageDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        finish();

    }
});
```

Important, set the dismissListener after You have build the Dialog.

Comment: I try this code but the Activity Will Close First And Then  AlertDialog() is close that's why the error is generate